# Is there a class annotation in FindBugs to ignore all warning in a file

Tags: findbugs

there is an annotation in FindBugs to ignore a set of errors,
for instance:

```
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings;
@SuppressWarnings(value="DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE", justification="...")
```

is there a way to ignore all types of errors for a java file,
using an annotation?

I am awared that a file can be excluded from the command line or a configuration file:
http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html

but for this particular case, I would need to define this exclusion modifying only that java file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the standard annotation with an empty string for the `value` attribute.

```
@SuppressWarnings(value = "")
```

If you use `@SuppressFBWarnings` instead of `@SuppressWarnings` to avoid the confusion with `java.lang.SuppressWarnings` and allow automatic importation in IDEs to work, you can even omit the `value` attribute entirely.

```
@SuppressFBWarnings
```